# How to iterate through JSON keys in Delphi

Tags: json, delphi

I have a generic JSON which comes with many unknown keys `{'OISADLKMKLS': 123, 'ASDMOA':54, 'aosdmaosdm':65}` I want to iterate to all these pairs, but I also need to discover the key name. Many examples on the internet don't show how to rescue the key, just the value.

I found this, which doesn't solve it all.

```
for var JsonPair in JsonObject do
  begin
    var element := JsonValue.ToString; //gives me "OISADLKMKLS":"123"
  end.
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `JsonPair.JsonString` to get the name (key) of the Json Pair.

[System.JSON.TJSONPair.JsonString](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.JSON.TJSONPair.JsonString)

Comment: thanks. Actually the KeyName is System.Json.TJsonPair.JsonString.Value
And the Value is System.Json.TJsonPair.JsonValue.Value

A really big confusion from embarcadero  :(